# Get bins of histogram in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, where I want to have the bins with the respecting ID to it in a new dataframe.

So the rawdata df looks like:

```
ID  mean
A    10
B    100000
C     30
....
```

how can I save the bins + range and respecting ID's in a new dataframe, that I get the outcome:

```
Bin_range   IDS
10-100      A,C,...
....
1000000-20000000000000  B,....
```

I started with:

```
a = np.hstack((df['mean'].normal(size=1000),

               df['mean'].normal(loc=5, scale=2, size=1000)))
```

but got the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'normal'
```

Note that the bins should be automatically define the ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna create bins then you can simply use `pd.cut`:

```
new_df = df.groupby(pd.cut(df['mean'], bins= [0,10,100,1000000,20000000000000, np.inf], include_lowest= True, right=False, labels= ['<10','10-100', '100-1000000', '1000000-20000000000000','20000000000000+'])).agg({'ID': ', '.join})
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
                         ID
mean                        
<10                     None
10-100                  A, C
100-1000000                B
1000000-20000000000000  None
20000000000000+         None
```

NOTE: you can customize the bin size and drop the `None` values later if required.

##### RANDOM BINS:

To create custom bin intervals you can use `pd.interval_range` you just need to specify the period and it'll create the bins for you:

```
new_df = df.groupby(pd.cut(df['mean'], bins =pd.interval_range(start=df['mean'].min() -1, end= df['mean'].max(), periods=4))).agg({'ID': ', '.join})
```

##### OUTPUT

```
                        ID
mean                      
(9.0, 25006.75]       A, C
(25006.75, 50004.5]   None
(50004.5, 75002.25]   None
(75002.25, 100000.0]     B
```

Comment: Sorry, I added a note, I want the bins automatically created, so that I don't have to define the ranges

Comment: So, is there any specific requirement or the bins can be random between the `min/max` value?

Comment: the bins can be random, like in a distplot/histplot